# shortcut to open multiple programmes and have them open a specific file

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, automator

When writing code for web i need to have several programmes and files open at the same time, i need :

- project folder open in sublime text
- terminal open and on a specific directory
- tower (git client) open on the correct project
- mamp open and running
- browser open and on to local server url

It takes me a few minutes to setup each time, is there a way i can automate these so that with one action all will open and be in the correct configuration ?

Im running osx 10.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes. The longer answer is, it can be done more then one way.

I'd probably opt for a bash script and wrap it in a application bundle using [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus), although you can use a Run Shell Script action in Automator too.

In Automator you might want to try the Watch Me Do action, although that will be slower then just a bash script.

Note that some things you mentioned may not be able to be bash scripted, can't say for sure because I do not use Tower or MAMP, although the others are bash scriptable

I can't give a complete answer as I do not use Tower or MAMP however for Sublime Text, Terminal and Safari the following works for me.

Note that Sublime Text includes a command line executable `subl` within its application bundle. The typical path might be, `/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl` and executing it with `--help` will display its internal help information.

The following script example could be used if you can ascertain the commands necessary for Tower and MAMP.

```
#!/bin/bash

/path/to/subl --project <project>
open -a Terminal /path/to/the/location/I/want
# Tower commands.
# MAMP commands.
open -a Safari http://127.0.0.1
```